# Google API Refresh Token and Access Token Questions (Java BE + Web App)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, refresh-token, google-oauth-java-client, auth-token

I want to do something very similar to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), in which I'm getting the `authCode` from web client and sending that authCode to a Java BE app to get credentials of an user and then, using the credential to gain access to google sheet api to create a spreadsheet on user's drive.

According to [google-api-java-client/oauth2 doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2):

> GoogleCredential takes care of automatically "refreshing" the token,
> which simply means getting a new access token.

Would I still be able to take advantage of the above statement, in which `GoogleCredential` automatically refreshes the token if I'm authenticating and asking for permission on the client web app - aka, I call the `grant offline` request on web app and then, getting the actual `GoogleCredential` in a Java BE app (using the `authCode`)? If so, how does that work? Why would others suggest to store the `refreshToken` in a db?

If I do decide to store in a db, would storing the `refreshToken` with the key as my app's unique identifier for a user be OK (instead of using the suggested `sub` identifier)? Is there a limit on the amount of time I can call the `token` to get a new accessToken per user? Even if an `accessToken` hasn't expired, is it better to just get a new `accessToken` for every new request (seems more secure)?